# Why is my function malfunctioning

Tags: php, function

Working on a class assignment and when I run this code

```
function paycheck1($hours,$payrate,$othours,$otrate){
        if ($hours > $othours){
            $total = "<tr><td>".($hours*$payrate)+($hours - $othours)*$otrate."</td></tr>";
        return $total;  
        }
        else{
            $total = "<tr><td>".$hours * $payrate."</td></tr>";
            return $total;
        }
}

$pay = 10;
$hours = 50;
$overtime_starts = 40;
$overtime_rate = 15; 
echo "<table>";
for ($i=0;$i<$hours;$i++){
echo paycheck1($i, $pay, $overtime_starts, $overtime_rate);
}
echo "</table>";
```

I get output like this

```
153045607590105120135
0
10
20
30
40.....
```

Why am I getting `153045607590105120135` When I run the code. If I remove the `($hours*$payrate)+` from the **function->if** it works just fine. Why am I getting what I use is an overflow error.

Comment: Does this help? `$total = "<tr><td>".($hours * $payrate)."</td></tr>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to find the problem in the source if you put newlines at the end of your html, like:

```
$total = "<tr><td>".($hours * $payrate)."</td></tr>\n";
```

Also, you have to pay attention to the order of operations, even with the `.` operator.

This line:

```
$total = "<tr><td>".($hours*$payrate)+($hours - $othours)*$otrate."</td></tr>\n";
```

Needs parenthesis:

```
$total = "<tr><td>".(($hours*$payrate)+($hours - $othours)*$otrate)."</td></tr>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all mathematical equations with ( ) when using strings.

Change line 4 to the following:

```
$total = "<tr><td>".(($hours*$payrate)+($hours - $othours)*$otrate)."</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like attempting to calculate the numeric total while also concatenating your "$total" string is causing the issue.  Either put parenthesis around the entire calculation or separate the calculation from the string output like this:

```
function paycheck1($hours, $payrate, $othours, $otrate){
        if ($hours > $othours){
            $numeric_total = ($hours*$payrate)+($hours - $othours)*$otrate; // calc total
            $total = "<tr><td>".$numeric_total."</td></tr>";
            return $total;  
        }
        else{
            $total = "<tr><td>".$hours * $payrate."</td></tr>";
            return $total;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a display glitch caused by your invalid markup.

Replace

```
$total = "<tr><td>".($hours*$payrate)+($hours - $othours)*$otrate."</td></tr>";
```

with

```
$total = "<tr><td>".(($hours*$payrate)+($hours - $othours)*$otrate)."</td></tr>";
```

to prevent the string from being messed up.

Answer (score 0):

According to me parenthesis around the mathematical calculation would solve this.

I would suggest to modify the function to return only value calculated with expression rather returning the HTML content for more simplicity.

```
    function paycheck1($hours,$payrate,$othours,$otrate){
    if ($hours > $othours){
        $total = ($hours*$payrate)+($hours - $othours)*$otrate;
    return $total;  
    }
    else{
        $total = $hours * $payrate;
        return $total;
    }
    }
    $pay = 10;
    $hours = 50;
    $overtime_starts = 40;
    $overtime_rate = 15; 
    echo "<table>";
    for ($i=0;$i<$hours;$i++){
    echo "<tr><td>".paycheck1($i, $pay, $overtime_starts, $overtime_rate)."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```